# Is it possible reference the value of a variable when building a closure in groovy, rather than the variable itself?

Tags: groovy, closures

I understand why

```
x = 'foo'
closure={print x}
x = 'bar'
closure()
```

will return 'bar', because the variable in the closure will always reference the current value of the variable.  But what i'd like to do is dynamically build a closure {print 'foo'} so that when I call the closure, it always prints the same thing, based on whatever x happened to be at the time I built the closure.  Is that possible?

Comment: That's not a closure ;-)

Comment: Sorry, I think a code block is what it's called?  I'm not super familiar with groovy.

Comment: Sorry, I was being pedantic. What you have shown is a closure, but what you describe you want is not the definition of a closure

Answer (score 1):

You can add a level of indirection with a method, so the closure closes over the method parameter instead of the external variable

```
def close(x) {
    { -> println x }
}

x = 1
closure = close(x)
x = 2
closure()
```

Or, you can do it with the (arguably less readable) double closure call:

```
x = 1
closure = { x -> { -> println x } }(x)
x = 2
closure()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [curry()](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/Closure.html#curry(java.lang.Object...)).

```
def x = 'foo'
def closure = { it }.curry(x)

x = 'bar'
assert closure() == 'foo'
```